# Django CBV Detailview

Tags: python, django, detailview

Hello Everybody excuse my english....
I am facing a problem with django.
I need to restrict object so only their  owners can print it.

Model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False) 
 prenom = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
 user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
```

View.py

```
class detailpost(DetailView):
 model = Post
 template_name = 'detail-post.html'
 context_object_name = 'post'
```

url.py

```
    url(r'detail-post/(?P<pk>[-\d]+)$', views.detailpost.as_view(), name='detailpost'),
```

This works properly but the problem is that every users can access to the post of another user (http://localhost:8000/detail-post/1). So my question is how can i do some stuff  befor rendering the page and see if the post belongs to the current user if yes  we print it else we redirect the user to another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override get() or post() method in your view class.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class detailpost(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'detail-post.html'
    context_object_name = 'post'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.post = Post.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        if self.post.user != request.user or not request.user.is_superuser:
            return  redirect('login')
        else:
            return super(detailpost, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you it works fine. I just remove the or not request.user.is_superuser so every user can access to their posts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) (new in Django 1.9) to make sure that only logged in users can access the view.

Then override the [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset) method, and filter the queryset so that it only includes posts by the logged-in user.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class DetailPost(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'detail-post.html'
    context_object_name = 'post'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(DetailPost, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

If the user views a post that does not belong to them, they will see a 404 page. If you must redirect the user instead of showing a 404, then you'll have to take a different approach.

Note that I have renamed your class `DetailPost` (CamelCase is recommended for classes in Django. You'll have to update your urls.py as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should override 'get()' method in your 'detailpost' class, so that it would be something like below:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
   queryset = self.model._default_manager.filter(user=request.user)
   self.object = self.get_object(queryset)
   context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
   return self.render_to_response(context)
```

It seems like it is the only way to pass User from Request instance to filter queryset.
I did not find that `DetailView` uses `self.request`